# URL rewrite of filters in category page magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I want to rewrite search filter query string like

```
https://website.com/mens.phtml?location=289
```

289 means - id of Delhi City

And i want to rewrite URL like

```
https://website.com/mens/delhi.html
```

I have created observer and tried to fill data in csv then trying to rewrite url:

```
class CustomUrl implements ObserverInterface
```

{
    protected $request;

```
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

{
         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
         $currentUrl =  $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();

         $file = "csv/url_data_sheet.csv";

        // check page if page is product detail page

        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
            $urldata = $_REQUEST;
            $data = array();
            $data['url'] = $currentUrl;
            $data['type'] = $_REQUEST['location'];
            $data['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];;
            $data_row[] = $data;

            $file = "csv/url_data_sheet.csv";

             if (file_exists($file)) {

                foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
                {
                    $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
                }

             } 

             if(!file_exists($file)){
                $filenew = fopen($file, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
            } else {
                $filenew = fopen($file,"w");
            }


            foreach ($data_row as $data)
            {
                fputcsv($filenew,$data);
            }

            fclose($filenew);

                }

           }
}
```

Please if someone can help me out. Thanks

Comment: So, you want to change the first url into the second one?

Comment: Yes, i want like this. please suggest for this

Comment: What is your code for the search?

Comment: 1) getting all filter url like (http//example.com/mens.html?location=289) data in csv with url, type, id
2) by this data, i am trying to bulk url rewrite

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question.

Comment: I have added code, please check

Comment: I meant the code, which is used for the search. So, the code, which creates the first link.

Comment: don't know code, so i am asking for that

Comment: How do you get to this url `https://website.com/mens.phtml?location=289`?

Comment: when we go any category and click on location filter then we get this type of url of filter : https://website.com/mens.phtml?location=289

Comment: So, what is the code for the location filter?